# How to extract values using eval() in tensorflow and how many times we need to launch session

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow we create graphs and then in order to pass the values to the graph we have to launch a session. In the following code  I launch session once and then try to print filter by two different methods. But I am unable to get result with eval. Does I need to mention tf.Session again to extract value by eval?  I also read that eval command uses default session. So according to my understanding I need to mention it once.

```
filter = tf.random_normal(shape=[2,1,1], seed=123)
sess=tf.Session()
print(sess.run(filter))
print(filter.eval())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you want `sess` to be your default session. You can do that in a couple of ways. One is as a context manager:

```
filter = tf.random_normal(shape=[2,1,1], seed=123)
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    print(sess.run(filter))
    print(filter.eval())
```

The other option is to use [`tf.InteractiveSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession), which is a regular session that registers itself as default on construction:

```
filter = tf.random_normal(shape=[2,1,1], seed=123)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(sess.run(filter))
print(filter.eval())
```

As its name suggests, [`tf.InteractiveSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession) is recommended for interactive use. Full programs or modules should prefer the context manager (or just avoid `.eval()`) to avoid mistakes.

EDIT: If you use the context manager, you can also use it to make sure that your session is closed too:

```
filter = tf.random_normal(shape=[2,1,1], seed=123)
with tf.Session() as sess, sess.as_default():
    print(sess.run(filter))
    print(filter.eval())
# sess will be closed after with block
```